# how can I make a uint32 in F#?

Tags: f#

I have an .NET api, from RabbitMQ, that takes a uint32

the method is:

```
void BasicQos(uint prefetchSize, ushort prefetchCount, bool global);
```

in C#:

```
channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
```

but in F#, the same line gives:

> [FS0001] This expression was expected to have type    'uint32'    but here has type    'int'

but I can't figure out how to declare a number as unsigned in F#; how can I do this?

UInt32 and UInt32Converter exist but I couldn't see how I could use them to convert / cast, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the docs page on literals [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals), but the short form is that you need the `u` suffix: `0u` is an unsigned 32-bit integral zero.  You could also use the `uint32` function to convert a signed 32-bit int to an unsigned 32-bit int, but this would be work done at runtime as opposed to a compile-time value.